# Getting stock data in a discipline manner from Yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-formats

I used the below code for downloading stock data from yahoo finance:-

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

    stocks = ["AXISBANK.NS", "HDFCBANK.NS", "ICICIBANK.NS" ,"INDUSINDBK.NS",
    "KOTAKBANK.NS",
    "SBIN.NS",
    "YESBANK.NS"]
    start = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2019,7,17)
    data = yf.download(stocks, start=start, end=end)
    data
```

I get the data in a below manner:-

[image]

I saved the data using panda:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# saving the dataframe 
df.to_csv('BANKING STOCK.csv')
```

I got the data in this format:-
[image]

But I ant my data in this format:-

[image]

Because this format is more convenient for analyzing data through SQL. How can I change the format of the data?

Comment: Pandas wide-to-long command could be helpful https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Comment: @Peter can you please post your code in the answer section

Comment: You may be interested in [How to deal with multi-level column names downloaded with yfinance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107594)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
data.stack().reset_index().rename(index=str, columns={"level_1": "Symbol"}).sort_values(['Symbol','Date'])
```

Output:

```
           Date       Symbol  Adj Close  ...     Low    Open     Volume
0    2018-01-01  AXISBANK.NS     564.80  ...  560.50  563.80    6943234
7    2018-01-02  AXISBANK.NS     558.81  ...  556.35  567.00    6292268
14   2018-01-03  AXISBANK.NS     559.75  ...  555.75  561.30    3990149
21   2018-01-04  AXISBANK.NS     559.21  ...  558.00  564.85    2766664
28   2018-01-05  AXISBANK.NS     562.55  ...  556.70  561.05    3249056
35   2018-01-08  AXISBANK.NS     564.75  ...  562.45  565.80    3770339
42   2018-01-09  AXISBANK.NS     564.60  ...  563.00  564.00    4607504
49   2018-01-10  AXISBANK.NS     562.10  ...  560.45  566.15    2411625
```

The basic operation is [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) that stacks the column headers into a multiindex. This multiindex is then converted to columns (`reset_index()`) which then get proper names. Finally the data are sorted by Symbol and Date as required.

---

Remark: You don't need `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`, `yf.download` already returns a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Sorry for late accepting @Stef. It will be more convenient for me if you describe your code.

Comment: @coding_ninza No problem. I added some explanations who the code works.

Comment: Than you very much @Stef